# Hibernate - good approaches to aggregate data and transform them into new entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I would need to make an aggregation of certain data stored in database via Hibernate, so I would like to use HQL to get data I need.

```
Transaction
    id
    userEmail
    moneyPaid
```

Now.. what is the best way to aggregate all moneyPaid by user determined by userEmail. I would like to get back entities that will have user email, with aggregated moneyPayd property.

What is the best and most elegant way to do that?

And possibly if I have another entity say User:

```
User
    id
    email
    address
```

Is there any convenient way not involving to much code that would join User with Transaction, aggregate moneyPaid and returned list of entities of totaly different type like:

```
AggregatedData
    email
    totalMoneyPaid
    address
```

I know some ways to do this but they are all but elegant and concise, any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> select u.email, sum(t.moneyPaid), u.address from Transaction t 
> left join t.user u
> group by u.email, u.address;
> ```

I'am ok with this query, if you don't want a `List<Object[]>` as return, you can write this :

```
select new org.sample.RequestResult(u.email, sum(t.moneyPaid), u.address) from Transaction t
left join t.user u
group by u.email, u.address;
```

Create an object `org.sample.RequestResult` with a constructor String email, Long (Or other, the type of your entity's field) moneyPaid, and String address

The query will return a `List<RequestResult>`

You can else just write `select new map(...)` which return will a Map from aliases to selected values

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.email, sum(t.moneyPaid), u.address from Transaction t 
left join t.user u
group by u.email, u.address;
```

For this to work, the Transaction entity must not have a userEmail property, but an ManyToOne association to the User entity.

The [hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/) contains everything you need to know about associations and aggregate functions. They're similar to SQL aggregate functions, obviously.

Note that the above query doesn't return entities, but a `List<Object[]>`, each `Object[]` containing three elements : the email, the total money paid, and the address. Up to you to loop over the list and crate a list of `AggregatedData` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to use HQL to query the result?
If so, I think group by statement in HQL would do.

```
select t.userEmail, sum(t.moneyPaid)
from Transaction t
group by t.userEmail
```

I am not sure what the returned type is(you can debug to find it). 
But I guess `List<List<Object>>` might work.
(it is weakly typed, so you have to do down cast before using it)

refer to hibernate website:
[Query with HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)